# Modifying Ros Driver Before Installing

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need to make some rather specific changes to a ros driver specifically to the ros-indigo-pointgrey-camera-driver, before installing it.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

thanks,

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221095/modifying-ros-driver-before-installing/) by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install from source, not using debian package.

You should download source to your workspace from https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver . After you can apply necessary changes and compile it with `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on 2015-11-18**:
thanks i'll give this a shot